# Add &nbsp; after word specified in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to add `&nbsp;` after the words I have defined in array. So I want it to come out: `Testing w&nbsp;it's ul.&nbsp;here`. Please help. I do not know how to do this.

```
$array = array('w','z','u','o','ul.');
$titleOld = 'Testing w it's ul. here';
$title = str_replace($array.' ','&nbsp;',$titleOld);
```

EDIT: I do something like this:

```
$nbspBefore = array(' w ',' z ',' u ',' o ',' ul. ');
$nbsp = array(' w&nbsp;',' z&nbsp;',' u&nbsp;',' o&nbsp;',' ul.&nbsp;');
$title = 'Testing w it's ul. here';
$title = str_replace($nbspBefore,$nbsp,$title);
```

It's not clean code I think, but it works fine.

EDIT 2: Okay, I did it another way, In JS.

```
var array=['w','z','u','o','ul.'],
    text = document.querySelector('selector');
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    text.innerHTML = text.textContent.replace(new RegExp(' '+array[i]+' ','g'),' '+array[i]+'&nbsp;');
}
```

Comment: don't you have a simpler way to define what you want to do, functionnaly, at a more general level ?

Comment: just take a look at example1, 3rd case, here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an array in this format into `str_replace()`:

```php
$array = ['word1' => 'word1&nbsp;', 'word2' => 'word2&nbsp;'];
```

You can get it like this:

```php
$words = ['word1', 'word2'];
$array = array_combine($words, $words); // ['word1' => 'word1', 'word2' => 'word2']
$finalArray = array_map(fn ($word) => $word . '&nbsp;', $array); // ['word1' => 'word1&nbsp;', 'word2' => 'word2&nbsp;']

$title = str_replace($finalArray, $titleOld);
```

Comment: `str_replace()` takes 3 arguments, not 2. And the result will be _"Testing w&nbsp; it's u&nbsp;l. here"_

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by space, and, check for each world if there is any match with the given array.

```
$array = array('w','z','u','o','ul.');
$titleOld = 'Testing w it\'s ul. here';

$words = explode(' ', $titleOld);
$titleNew = trim(join('', array_map(function($word) use ($array) {
    return $word . (in_array($word, $array) ? "&nbsp;" : ' ');
}, $words)));

echo $titleNew; // "Testing w&nbsp;it's ul.&nbsp;here"
```

Or, as of PHP 7.4:

```
$titleNew = trim(join('', array_map(fn($word) => 
    $word . (in_array($word, $array) ? "&nbsp;" : ' '),
    $words)));
```

<sub>Online examples : [up to 7.3](https://3v4l.org/3HffW), [as of 7.4](https://3v4l.org/4D7UB).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier by using regular expressions.

```php
$array = array('w','z','u','o','ul.');
$titleOld = "Testing w it's ul. here cappuccino";

array_map(function ($w) use (&$titleOld) {

    $titleOld = preg_replace("/\b" . $w . "\s{1}\b/", "$w&nbsp;", $titleOld);

}, $array);

echo $titleOld;  // Testing w&nbsp;it's ul.&nbsp;here cappuccino
```

Comment: But this added &nbsp; when is the letter in word, for example: "cappuccino&nbsp;" and I want only after "o" itself

Comment: @test, Well, it's because your specifications were not explicit. No worries, I've updated my answer. Please, try out the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach using **[foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** to loop over the array [exploded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by space in sentence and check if any word match the replacable words in `array` we want by using **[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** method, if so add `&nbsp;` otherwise just leave it as it is and add a space.

```php
$array = array('w','z','u','o','ul.');
$titleOld = 'Testing w it\'s ul. here';

$words = explode(' ', $titleOld);
$title = '';
foreach ($words as $i=>$word) {
    if(in_array($word,$array)){
        $title.=$word.'&nbsp;';
    }else{
        if($i===count($words)-1)
            $title.=$word;
        else
            $title.=$word." ";
    }
}
echo $title;//Testing w&nbsp;it's ul.&nbsp;here
```

*update*: I had a problem a space at the end, so i solve it by adding index to foreach in order to track if the word is the last, if so we shouldn't add a space otherwise we add a space.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$search = array('w ', 'z ', 'u ', 'o ', 'ul. ');
$replace = array('w&nbsp;', 'z&nbsp;', 'u&nbsp;', 'o&nbsp;', 'ul.&nbsp;');
$titleOld = "Testing w it's ul. here";
$title = str_replace($search, $replace, $titleOld);
```

(https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php, 1st example, 3rd case)